# How do I insert a Boolean Value into my SQLite Database?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

This is my function to add Data:

```
public boolean addData(String item1, boolean done) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL2, item1);
        cv.put(COL3, done);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv );

        //if date was inserted incorrectly it will return -1, thus returning false here
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And how I create my Database plus the column and table names:

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylist.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mylist_data";
public static final String COL1 = "id";
public static final String COL2 = "name";
public static final String COL3 = "isdone";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +  " 
 ("+ COL1 +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
   + COL2 + " TEXT,"
   + COL3 +" BOOLEAN )";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}
```

When executed, the insert statement returns "-1", meaning it did not complete the insertion. Any idea how to save a boolean value into a Database?

(The issue does reside with the boolean, since when commented out of code, i can insert values without problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html in 2.1

use an integer with values 0 and 1 instead.

You are using C# or Java? Please tag it accordingly.

And Set COL3 in the table creation sql to INTEGER and change line "`cv.put(COL3, done);`" to "`cv.put(COL3, done? 1: 0);`":

```
public boolean addData(String item1, boolean done) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL2, item1);
        cv.put(COL3, done? 1: 0);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv );

        return (result != -1); 
    }
```

I removed comment of -1, because it is documented in reference https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues) therefore comment is void.

This is a question in C# - I thought first - but now in Java:

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylist.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mylist_data";
public static final String COL1 = "id";
public static final String COL2 = "name";
public static final String COL3 = "isdone";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +  " 
 ("+ COL1 +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
   + COL2 + " TEXT,"
   + COL3 +" INTEGER)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}
```